# Point clouds registration

Tags: point-cloud-library, realsense

I am trying to make a 3D scanner based on turntable. This 3D scanner should create a point cloud model to meause of object length, hight and depth. I am working with realsense d435  RGBD camera. While turntable is rotating, I get the point clouds of object that wants to scan. My question is that how can I join these point clouds that has different rotation angle.

My steps are:

1. Get the point cloud of object. ( I already got it)
2. Transform the axes of point cloud to world coordinate system. I mean when I import it to meshlab. It should be on xy axis. I made it to)
3. Use rotation matrix to rotate the point cloud data for real position. I mean, I get the point cloud data that has 90 degree angle from turntable. When I try the rotate it about z axis, it rotates. But the point clouds has 0 degree angle and 90 degree angle doesnt match.

How can I get over from this problem?